# Несколько вопросов по конфигурированию Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

При конфигурировании проекта в `Webpack` столкнулся со следующими вопросами:

1. Использую `html-webpack-plugin` и он генерирует базовый
   `html-документ`. Можно ли задать какие-то настройки данному
   плагину,чтобы при создании html внести туда `dom-элементы`(к примеру
   мне нужно внести div с id,дабы отрендерить в нем react-приложение)?
2. Как в webpack'е подключаются сторонние библиотеки\фреймворки?К
   примеру мне нужно подключить bootstrap. Раньше работал  с Gulp. там
   я просто указывал путь до стилей js библиотек, которые были
   установлены в папке node_modules. В случае с webpack этот момент мне непонятен.

Собственно сам webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');

//logs config
const stats = {
    assets: true
    , children: false
    , chunks: false
    , hash: false
    , modules: false
    , publicPath: false
    , timings: true
    , version: false
    , warnings: true
    , colors: {
        green: '\u001b[32m'
    }
};

module.exports = {

  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['es2015',"stage-0","react"] }
      }],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),

    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
        loader: "css-loader!sass-loader",
      }),
    },

    ],
  },

  devtool: "source-map",

  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    host: "localhost",
    stats: 'errors-only',
    contentBase: __dirname + '/src',
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'react-calendar',
        filename: 'index.html',

    }),
    extractCSS,
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
        warnings: false,
        }
    }),
  ],
}
```

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации. с помощью опции template  прокинул свой шаблон. вас не затруднит эти комментарии вынести в овтет,чтобы я его выбрал и мы закрыли вопрос?

Comment: вынес в ответ__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В [документации соответствующего плагина](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) упоминается конфиг [template](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md). 
   В теории с его помощью можно прокинуть почти любой html-шаблон или голую htmlку
2. Подключение сторонних библиотек разного типа неплохо документировано. Например для библиотек которые по старинке пишут в глобал скоуп есть [конфиг externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/). С распространенными форматами форматами модулей webpack 2 работает из коробки. webpack 1 не работает из коробки с es6 модулями и для их работы нужен соответствующий loader.
3. Сторонние цсс можно во-первых просто залинковать в исходном шаблоне. Можно также пойти слегка более сложным путем, и с помощью [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) и [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) обеспечить загрузку css в js-бандлы. Возможно есть и другие пути.
4. Также для работы со сторонними библиотеками может помочь [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader)

Comment: спасибо за подсказку;)